# What is the easiest way to get a 50x DC-DC voltage increase?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, spark

I want to have a 3-4 kV DC output to feed a marx generator in which I am planning to use 4kV ceramic capacitors. I have 2 DC power supplies @ 30V 6A rates, so I can have at most 60V DC input by using them in series. **What is the best or easiest way to have that approximately 50-60x voltage gain?**

I don't think the output current will be important because I will only need fast charge and discharge of capacitors to 3-4kV / from 3-4kV.

Comment: What are your voltage and current requirements for the output current and voltage?

Comment: If the things I already wrote are not the requirements you want, I am not sure I can answer your question. I want 3kV to 4kV output voltage ( so not too precise, anything between 3 and 4 kV is ok ) and current is not important( but this is my let's say guess, I intuitively think that for powering a marx generator, a very small current will not be a problem, if it is please let me know). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds like a flyback would be the easiest approach.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I forgot to mention you.

Comment: microwave oven transformer. 3.5kV  be very careful.

Comment: @Jasen do most of microwave ovens have it? Also what is their input voltage?

Comment: I could have sworn I saw this exact question earlier today.  Now it's gone.

Comment: @JRE you are right, it was my question but i deleted it and reasked with some modifications

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (at least on my knowledge) to do that using only DC voltages all the way.

At some point you have to convert them to AC in order to use (for example) a voltage doubler.

In fact, that would be my solution if I have to do this: dc source -> convert to AC --> a series of voltage doublers or multipliers -> rectify/filter the output --> enjoy your HV

You can look for voltage doubler, it is a really simple circuit, the  only thing tha you  have to be carefull about is the insulation: it havs to be good, really good

**UPDATE** : you can look for voltage doublers or voltage multipliers, here is a good explanation:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/voltage-multiplier-circuit.html

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Comment: yw! just remember to mark this as the correct answer if you don't find a better option

Comment: Voltage doublers automatically rectify the output.  Low voltage AC in, high voltage DC out.  The draw back is that you can't get much current out of them.

Comment: @JRE for my case, do you think not being able to get much current would have a negative effect?

Comment: Lower current = longer time until the marx generator can make pulse.  It also means that if your leakage (in the capacitors for the marx generator) is too high then you will never get enough charge stored for the discharge.

Comment: Thing is, a microwave oven **has** a [high voltage DC output about like you want, and at fairly high current.](http://www.vk3hz.net/amps/Microwave_Oven_Inverter_HV_Power_Supply.pdf)

Comment: @JRE thanks a lot, I will check it definetly.